# Why does slicing a non-root base class produce the correct answer?

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, object-slicing

I have a case in my code where I'd like to use object slicing, but I'm trying to determine if it's safe or smart to do it. In trying to determine this, I ran the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Dog{

    public:
        Dog( int x )
            :x{x}
        {

        };

        int x;

};


class Spaniel: public Dog{

    public:
        Spaniel( int x, int y )
            :Dog{x}, y{y}
        {

        }

        int y;

};


class Green{

    public:
     Green( int q )
         :q{q}
     {

     }

     int q;

};


class GreenSpaniel: public Spaniel, public Green{

   public:
        GreenSpaniel( int x, int y, int q, int z )
            :Spaniel{x,y}, Green{q}, z{z}
        {

        }

        int z;

};



int main(){

    GreenSpaniel jerry{ 1,2,3,4 };

    Green fred = jerry;

    cout << fred.q << endl;  //correctly displays "3"

    return 0;

}
```

I was expecting it to return 1 because the base class was not the top-most (root), but it displays 3. So, my question is why/how is it showing the correct answer and **is this a safe practice**? How would your answer change if any of the classes had virtual tables? If you don't consider it safe, do you have any workarounds for copying a non-root base object from a derived object?

I ran this in linux under gcc 4.6.3 with the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cc
```

Comment: It's probably neither safe nor smart, but it is deterministic: The `Green` copy constructor copies the `Green` subobject of your `jerry` object, which has `q` set to `3`.

Comment: Do you know of a section of the standard that addresses this (ie. guarantees its determinism?)

Comment: no, it is not a safe practice, and people usually like to avoid slicing, because of problems it introduces. Although your program is well defined (see answers bellow)

Comment: It is not a safe practice leaving member variable public, which will be override(usually not what we what) silently(with no error or warning) with assignment.

Comment: @BЈовић well it certainly seems that, even if it were safe, it would be unintuitive (and therefore a reason to be avoided)

Comment: C++11 4.10/3 (pointer conversion), I'd say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that fred is being constructed using a compiler-synthesized copy constructor, which takes `const Green&` as an argument. It performs a shallow copy of the content of the Green portion of jerry.

you would have seen the same result if you used

```
const Green& fred = jerry;
```

where no copy is being carried out, you are just accessing the jerry portion of jerry, by giving it the name `fred`.

As for the other part of the question, there is nothing un-safe about your design, just it's "complex" and you need to be aware of what's happening. You might want to read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mi-disciplines.html) and related pages for some discussion on the topic.

Of course you can define your own copy constructor(s)/operator(s) having different behaviour. Or you can just inhibit the compiler to generate them

> The traditional way to deal with these is to declare a private copy constructor and copy assignment, and then document why this is
>   done.  A new alternative was introduced in C++2011, declaring a copy
>   constructor and a copy assignment operator, but marking both as
>   deleted.  Deriving from noncopyable is simpler and clearer, and
>   doesn't require additional documentation.

[source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable)

Comment: Using that rationale, why does **Green fred(jerry);** still result in 3?

Comment: Do you know of a way to generate the compiler-generated constructors in gcc?

Comment: for the same reason: Green fred(jerry) constructs an object of type Green by means of invoking the copy constructor passing jerry as an argument.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. The compiler generates much more than that

Comment: I'm also guessing that, because it's a reference, classes with a vtable would not make a difference?